# userform textbox to display active sheet name

Tags: excel, vba

In my workbook there are 50 worksheets, I have created a userform which pop up a textbox which can help me change the sheet name now I want that when I toggle through different worksheets then the current worksheet name should display in that textbox and then I will modify the sheet name with the code which is stated below.

Can you please tell me a code line with the help of which the textbox displays the current worksheet name.

Please find below the code with the help of which I can change the existing worksheet name by typing the name in the textbox `Sheetnametext`

```
Private Sub Sheetnametext_Change()

'If the length of the entry is greater than 31 characters, disallow the entry.

If Len(Sheetnametext) > 31 Then
    MsgBox "Worksheet tab names cannot be greater than 31 characters in length." & vbCrLf & "You entered " & mysheetname & ", which has " & Len(mysheetname) & " characters.", , "Keep it under 31 characters"
    Exit Sub
End If

'Sheet tab names cannot contain the characters /, \, [, ], *, ?, or :. 'Verify that none of these characters are present in the cell's entry.
Dim IllegalCharacter(1 To 7) As String, i As Integer

IllegalCharacter(1) = "/"
IllegalCharacter(2) = "\"
IllegalCharacter(3) = "["
IllegalCharacter(4) = "]"
IllegalCharacter(5) = "*"
IllegalCharacter(6) = "?"
IllegalCharacter(7) = ":"

For i = 1 To 7
    If InStr(Sheetnametext, (IllegalCharacter(i))) > 0 Then
        MsgBox "You used a character that violates sheet naming rules." & vbCrLf & vbCrLf & "Please re-enter a sheet name without the ''" & IllegalCharacter(i) & "'' character.", 48, "Not a possible sheet name !!"
        Exit Sub
    End If
Next i

'Verify that the proposed sheet name does not already exist in the workbook.
Dim strSheetName As String, wks As Worksheet, bln As Boolean

strSheetName = Trim(Sheetnametext)

On Error Resume Next
Set wks = ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets(strSheetName)
On Error Resume Next

If Not wks Is Nothing Then
    bln = True
Else
    bln = False
    Err.Clear
End If

'History is a reserved word, so a sheet cannot be named History.
If UCase(mysheetname) = "HISTORY" Then
    MsgBox "A sheet cannot be named History, which is a reserved word.", 48, "Not allowed"
    Exit Sub
End If

'If the worksheet name does not already exist, name the active sheet as the InputBox entry.
'Otherwise, advise the user that duplicate sheet names are not allowed.
If bln = False Then
    ActiveSheet.Name = strSheetName
End If

End Sub
```

Comment: If I am trying Sheetnametext.Text = ActiveSheet.Name then its displaying the current sheet name but its not allowing me to write anything in the textbox.

Answer (score 0):

Astha better you use a Listbox to navigate Sheets in Workbook,, try this code.

Private Sub UserForm_Initialize()

Dim N As Long 
For N = 1 To ActiveWorkbook.Sheets.Count     ListBox1.AddItem ActiveWorkbook.Sheets(N).Name 
Next N

End Sub

Comment: So shud I change my previous code also from textbox (Sheetnametext) to Listbox1

Comment: If you use my codes will be enough to get solution.

Comment: You want me to create another Listbox because this is a textbox so your code is not working

Comment: Yes create a Listbox because it can hold list of Values.

Comment: I dont want list of values I basically want that when I click on any worksheet that worksheet name should highlight in the textbox and then I can modify it to whatever name i want

Comment: I have created a textbox which is helping me to change the name to whatever I want but when I am clicking on any of the worksheet the name of the worksheet is not displaying in the textbox

Comment: Astha please create LISTBOX,, and use the code I've suggested, Textbox will not work.